# Dynamic MySQL Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, dynamic

Is it possible in **MySQL** to create tables that use other column from another table dynamically (same idea as extending a class in **PHP**). Example:

```
table1
    table1_id
    column1
    column2
    column3

table2
    table2_id
    column4
    column5
```

So when I query **table2** I get all the columns from **table1** like:

```
SELECT table1_id,column1,column2,column3,table2_id,column4,column5 FROM table2;
```

Comment: Do you only want to execute selects against this dataset?  Also, are there columns within each table that relate to the other table?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html  You might want to look into using views

Comment: Depending on how "dynamic" it needs to be, creating and destroying views might not be worthwhile.  A JOIN might be better.

Comment: I think, it is not possible. You can use a join statement to retrieve all data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
CREATE VIEW t2_view AS <SELECT stuff FROM t1,t2> (not sure exactly how you want to join t1 and t2)

SELECT * FROM t2_view;
```

Something like that is what you are looking for I think.

Comment: took me a little while to understands what is a view and how it works but i got it now, i like that thanks